# Как сделать тетрис в Java (Eclipse)?

Tags: алгоритм, java

Как сделать тетрис в Java (Eclipse)?

Comment: лучше напишите игру которая предлагает вам отгадывать загаданную програмой цифру из диапазона. сначала консольное приложение потом с GUI

Comment: В GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (в других, наверное, тоже) есть исходник на Лисп. Попробуйте странслировать его (руками, с помощью Eclipse) в Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Tetris {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.tetris.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В сети много источников:

- [Tetris meets the Java bean](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tetris/)
- [Tetris Source](http://www.mit.edu/people/nathanw/java/TetrisSrc.html)

Искать по словам: java tetris source.

Comment: Так я не могу запустить игру! Что мне делать?

Comment: и вот такая ошыбка:                                                         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 tetris cannot be resolved or is not a field

 at Tetris.main(Tetris.java:3)

Comment: Этот комментарий, я так понимаю, относится к другому ответу. Если вы не поняли, что @dzhioev пошутил, это значит, что вам нужно еще подучить язык, прежде чем браться за GUI и начинать разрабатывать тетрис. Или воспользоваться предложенными участником @Петрович ссылками.

Comment: Я воспользовался сылками Петровича, но когда я запускал програму вот что было
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: tetris cannot be resolved or is not a field at Tetris.main(Tetris.java:3)